# jQuery code is not working when document is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an entire code working inside $(document).ready(... function, but **ONLY** this part of the code isn't working. Any tips?

Code:

```
$(".ui-button-icon-primary.ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").click(function() {
    console.log("next");
    days += 1;
    console.log(days);
});
$(".ui-button-icon-primary.ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").click(function() {
    console.log("previous");
    days -= 1;
    console.log(days);
});
```

**HINT:** When I put this code on browser's console, it works. jQuery was loaded correctly on the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? What exactly is not working? If you mean that the event handlers are not bound, then that's likely because the elements don't exist yet.

Comment: is this part of a button or other plugin that creates those classes?

Comment: Maybe you are re-creating, or generating the html element you're listening for after the script? try $("body").on("click" , function(){ ... }); and see if it works.

Comment: Are those elements you are binding to already in the DOM or are they added after the fact? You probably need to add more context here.

Comment: @FelixKling what i mean is, not even the console.log is printing in console.

Comment: use event delegation...if it works manually in console will work delegated also

Comment: Is a button of another plugin, it's generated dynamically..

Comment: @daniel_serretti It sounds like you have a runtime error before those lines. Does the console report any errors?

Comment: @Stryner zero erros before that..

Comment: @charlietfl I will try the delegate thing..

Comment: @Sergeon i will try it too..

Comment: @Stryner if selector is not found jQuery will fail silently

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't realize "not even the console.log is printing" was referring to the _inside_ of the click handler. I really shouldn't skim over things so quickly. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind with document

```
$(document).on("click",".ui-button-icon-primary.ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next",function() {

});
```